# How to delete a chart set in a specific range in a spreadsheet, using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

I got a code building charts in the active cell's row, in column 9.
Now, before a script deletes the source sheet of that chart, I'd like to get the chart set within that specific range (row,Col) and delete it.

```
var charts1 = newSheet.getCharts();
      chart = charts1[charts1.length - 1];
      chart = newSheet.newChart()
        .asLineChart()
        .addRange(newSheet.getRange(ticker + '!M71:P175'))
        .setMergeStrategy(Charts.ChartMergeStrategy.MERGE_COLUMNS)
        .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(false)
        .setNumHeaders(1)
        .setHiddenDimensionStrategy(Charts.ChartHiddenDimensionStrategy.IGNORE_BOTH)
        .setOption('bubble.stroke', '#000000')
        .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', false)
        // ...other .setOption()'s...
        .setOption('width', 305)
        .setPosition(activeCell, 9, 1, 1) //This is where the chart is set to be built
        .build();
      listOfStocks.insertChart(chart);
```

I've tried getting that range, but `getCharts()` to then delete it, but nothing of this sort comes up as an option.

How can this be done?

Comment: look at [Class Container Info](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/container-info?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks, @Cooper! I had a hard time interpreting the documentation...working on it little by little, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to remove a chart using the coordinate of cell on the chart using Google Apps Script.

In order to remove the chart, you can use the method of `removeChart` in Class Sheet. And, the coordinate of the chart can be retrieved by the method of `getContainerInfo`. When the sample script is prepared using these methods, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, please set the variables of `searchRow`, `searchColumn` and `sheetName`.

```
function myFunction() {
  const searchRow = 1;
  const searchColumn = 9;
  const sheetName = "Sheet1";

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  sheet.getCharts().forEach(c => {
    const container = c.getContainerInfo();
    if (container.getAnchorRow() == searchRow && container.getAnchorColumn() == searchColumn) {
      sheet.removeChart(c);
    }
  });
}
```

- In this sample script, the chart which is put to the cell "I1" is removed. In this case, this coordinate is the same with the upper left of the chart.

#### Note:

- If you want to remove all charts in the column "I", you can also use the following script.

  ```
    const searchColumn = 9;
    const sheetName = "Sheet1";

    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
    sheet.getCharts().forEach(c => {
      const container = c.getContainerInfo();
      if (container.getAnchorColumn() == searchColumn) {
        sheet.removeChart(c);
      }
    });
  ```

#### References:

- [removeChart(chart)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#removechartchart)
- [getContainerInfo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart#getcontainerinfo)

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I even tried reading through the documentation, but my poor knowledge still doesn't allow for appropriate interpretation.

Comment: I ended modifying it a bit so as to have all charts of a row deleted, instead of the column option. Perfect! Thank you!